# Postfix - send all notify_classes except failed authentication

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

How do I configure Postfix/Dovecot to not send errors to the postmaster regarding failed authentication? A botnet continually hammers my server, and I end up with hundreds of these emails:

```
Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 jensen.cf ESMTP Postfix
 In:  HELO jensen.cf
 Out: 250 jensen.cf
 In:  AUTH LOGIN
 Out: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye


For other details, see the local mail logfile
```

I would still like to receive other failures/errors as postmaster, but I do not want these sort of messages.

Here's excerpts of my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/[xxxxxxx].pem 
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/[xxxxxx].key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    permit

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth


smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unverified_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname


notify_classes=bounce,data,delay,policy,protocol,resource,software
```

Comment: `notify_classes = resource, software`, anything more is not appropriate for a mail server of any meaningful size.  Unrelated: don't accept `HELO` / `EHLO` with your own domain name from outside your network.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you wouldn't consider an iptables rule to block the offending remote host? or is that a waste of time when dealing with a botnet?

Comment: @the_velour_fog It's a waste of time first because Postfix can deal with the junk on its own, and second because you wouldn't catch all offending IPs even if you wanted. You can however use something like OpenBSD's `spamd`. That _does_ punish bot networks pretty badly, and it's almost completely automated.

Answer (score 0):

@Kenneth: Same here, but you may have another problem. The message "authentication not enabled" means just that. Try "postfconf smtpd_sasl_auth_enable", it seems you have it set to "no" (the default) instead of "yes", but in that case, your legitimate clients won't be able to authenticate either.

I had no such clients, and had left it at "no". Setting it to "yes" took care of the error notification mails. I now only get "LOGIN authentication failed" in the logs.

@SatoKatsura : the HELO/EHLO suggestion is a good one, it's an old spammer trick. But in this case it won't help, since the restriction rule normally wouldn't fire until the client made it past the logon, and to the "RCPT TO" stage. See the docs for "smtpd_delay_reject" (defaults to "yes").